# What are portfolio weights of a portfolio that costs nothing?

Tags: portfolio

Say I go out and invest 5 dollars in Microsoft, and I do so by shorting some amount of IBM stocks such that I exactly finance my Microsoft investment.

This portfolio has zero cost. So ... what are the "weights"?

Weights are defined as the dollar amount invested in some stock divided by the total dollar amount invested, but the total dollar amount invested is zero, and division by zero isn't defined.

So, in this case, what are the "weights"?

Answer (score 1):

The "weights" are calculated separately. In your case, you would be 100% long MSFT and 100% short IBM.

Here's a breakdown of an income  fund that I was looking at a while back   As you can see, the positions are segregated other than effect of proceeds received from the short side being added to the long side in the Total row.

```
                       Net %     Long %       Short %                      

 1. Cash                6.57      21.45        14.88 
 2. US Stocks           8.55       8.55         0.00 
 3. Non US Stocks       4.87       4.87         0.00 
 4. Bonds              68.65      77.93         9.27 
 5. Other              11.35      11.40         0.05 
 6. Total             100.00     124.20        24.20
```